# Oracle 11g update of rows in a table with millions of records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am working on a table which has many fields and 100 million data and has a composite key over some fields. Sample table **emp** with few rows out of millions is shown below:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
|   11 |   21 |   31 | X    |
|   12 |   22 |   32 | X    |
|   14 |   24 |   34 | X    |
|   11 |   21 |   31 | 555  |
|   11 |   21 |   31 | 551  |
|   12 |   22 |   32 | 89   |
|   14 |   24 |   34 | 45   |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Suppose the composite is key is over `Col1` to `Col4`. Imagine Col1, Col2, Col3 together represent a group Id. First row has `Col4` as `X` and so I need to select all records from table whose `Col1 = 11` and `Col2 = 21` and `Col3 = 31`. Next since second row is 12,22,32,'X', I need select all rows with `Col1 = 11` and `Col2 = 22` and `Col3=32`. And so on for all cases where `Col4 =X`.

I tried using for loop with cursor but it is taking lot of time since the table has 100 million data and composite key. It is taking very very long time.

Pseudo code of loop statement i tried:

```
result= select Col1,Col2,Col3 from emp where `Col4=X`.
for each row in result
do
   finalresult += select * from table where Col1 = row.Col1 and Col2 = row.Col2 and Col3 = row.Col3
done
```

**finalresult** to have all the required data. But this is running for a very long time.

Also I tried merge to update as below

```
    merge into emp t1
    using (select * from emp t where t.col4=X) t2
    on t1.col1=t2.col1
    and t1.col2=t2.col2
    and t1.col3=t3.col3
    when matched then update set col4=Y
and t1.col4!='X';
```

But this is not updating any rows.

I would really appreciate some help with this problem.

Comment: Did you try a simple update query?

Comment: What you said is not clear - which rows must be updated to have Col4=Y, the rows where currently Col4=X, or all the other rows? Then - do NOT do this in a loop, do NOT use cursors etc., that will take two years to complete. Don't try to rake leaves with a hammer; the hammer is to drive nails. Rake leaves with a rake. That is: use the UPDATE statement (plain SQL, no need for procedural code like loops).

Comment: I doubt that the statement you show will even compile, for at least a couple of reasons (so what do you mean by "returning 0 rows"???) - first, you can't set col4=Y, it should be ='Y', and second the last line is out of place (did you mean WHERE t1. ...  and not AND t1. ...?) THEN: How are col1-col4 going to continue to be primary key if you are going to have duplicates, by changing the values in col4 to 'Y' wherever it is not 'X' right now? Even if you make the syntax work, the primary key constraint should reject most changes. The requirement itself makes no sense!

Comment: The straight forward update query is most often the fastest. If you need it faster you will need to change the physical layout, for example have paritions. But I am ot sure you fully descibed what the actual rules you want to code are.

Comment: @mathguy Sorry. I think i didnt put up my question clearly. I have updated the question. Hope it is clear. I am not sure how to write using simple UPDATE and avoiding loop statement.

Comment: The question is still unclear. You have groups identified by (col1||col2||col3) right? And if some group has one or more rows with col4='X' you want to set col4='Y' for every other row in that group (rows with col4 != 'X')? Am I right?

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin yes that is the intention. Or instead of update to 'Y', if i am able to do a select of all records meeting the criteria, that would also help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
  from emp x
 where x.col4 != 'X'
   and exists (select 1
                 from emp y
                where x.col1 = y.col1
                  and x.col2 = y.col2
                  and x.col3 = y.col3
                  and y.col4 = 'X')
```